# H2O POJO causing javac java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: javac, h2o

I have a distributed random forest POJO model using the default model setting except for:

`ntrees` = 150

`max_depth` = 50

`min_rows` = 5

Here are the full settings:

> buildModel 'drf', {"model_id":"drf-335270ee-8970-4855-b521-c4fb4ca184f5","training_frame":"frame_0.750","validation_frame":"frame_0.250","nfolds":0,"response_column":"DENIAL","ignored_columns":["tx_match_date"],"ignore_const_cols":true,"ntrees":"150","max_depth":"50","min_rows":"5","nbins":20,"seed":-1,"mtries":-1,"sample_rate":0.6320000290870667,"score_each_iteration":true,"score_tree_interval":0,"balance_classes":false,"nbins_top_level":1024,"nbins_cats":1024,"r2_stopping":1.7976931348623157e+308,"stopping_rounds":0,"stopping_metric":"AUTO","stopping_tolerance":0.001,"max_runtime_secs":0,"checkpoint":"","col_sample_rate_per_tree":1,"min_split_improvement":0.00001,"histogram_type":"AUTO","categorical_encoding":"AUTO","build_tree_one_node":false,"sample_rate_per_class":[],"binomial_double_trees":true,"col_sample_rate_change_per_level":1,"calibrate_model":false}

When I try to compile the pojo with:

```
$javac -cp "h2o-genmodel.jar" -J-Xmx2g -J-XX:MaxPermSize=128m drf_335270ee_8970_4855_b521_c4fb4ca184f5.java
```

I get the following error.

> An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_131). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.util.BaseFileManager$ByteBufferCache.get(BaseFileManager.java:325)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.util.BaseFileManager.makeByteBuffer(BaseFileManager.java:294)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.file.RegularFileObject.getCharContent(RegularFileObject.java:114)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.file.RegularFileObject.getCharContent(RegularFileObject.java:53)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.readSource(JavaCompiler.java:602)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:665)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:950)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:56)
>           at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:42)

I don't get this error when replacing the DRF model with a deep learning pojo that I have also downloaded from h2o's Flow UI, so I'm thinking it is likely related to the `drf_335270ee_8970_4855_b521_c4fb4ca184f5.java` file (note that the POJO was too big to preview in H2O's Flow UI). What could be going on here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to compile an H2O random forest POJO, you can download and use a MOJO instead in almost exactly the same way without needing the compile step.

See:

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html

Comment: In h2o Flow, I'm assuming that the MOJO the the thing that is referred to as the "Model Deployment Package." Is this correct?

Comment: @reedv Yes, and we will update the text on the button to make that more clear.